# RxSwift: enable/disable button based on textfields are not empty

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have to enable a button based on the characters count on two textfields using RxSwift

```
@IBOutlet weak var userTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonToEnableDisable: UIButton!

var enabledObservable = combineLatest(userTextField.rx_text, passwordTextField.rx_text) 
{ (user,password) in
   self.loginButton.enabled = a.characters.count > 0 && b.characters.count > 0
}
```

Finally i acomplish by doing this, but i'm not sure if its the best way:

```
    _ = combineLatest(emailTextField.rx_text, passwordTextField.rx_text) { (a: String, b:String) in
        self.loginButton.enabled = (a.characters.count > 0 && b.characters.count > 0)
    }.subscribeNext { (result) -> Void in
    }
```

Edit final version:

```
    _ = combineLatest(emailTextField.rx_text, passwordTextField.rx_text) { (a: String, b:String) in
        return (a.characters.count > 0 && b.characters.count > 0)
        }.subscribeNext { enabled in
            self.loginButton.alpha = enabled ? 1 : 0.5
            self.loginButton.enabled = enabled
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 21):

If I understood you correctly, You probably want something like this

```
  let loginValidation = loginTextFiled
     .rx_text
     .map({!$0.isEmpty})
     .shareReplay(1)

  let userNameValidation = passwordTextField
     .rx_text
     .map({!$0.isEmpty})
     .shareReplay(1)

  let enableButton = combineLatest(loginValidation, userNameValidation) { (login, name) in
     return login && name
  }

  enableButton
     .bindTo(loginButton.rx_enabled)
     .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

For more details I suggest you to look at [RxExamples](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples)

There you can find a lot of answers to the common problems.
Have fun =)

Comment: Thanks, this got me going!

Answer (score 3):

In RxSwift Latest

```
let nameValidation = self.userNameTxtFld
    .rx.text
    .map({!($0?.isEmptyString())!})
    .share(replay: 1)

    let pwdValidation = passwdTxtFld
        .rx.text
    .map({!($0?.isEmptyString())!})
    .share(replay: 1)


    let enableButton = Observable.combineLatest(nameValidation, pwdValidation) { $0 && $1 }
        .share(replay: 1)

    enableButton
        .bind(to: loginBtn.rx.isEnabled)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```